# Find records with combo box from form that contains mulitple tables in ACCES 2013

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am having some trouble creating a drop-down list for a form that contains multiple tables.

If i have 1 table then using combo box is simple as you just click the option:
find a record on my form based on the value I selected in my combo box.

as I have 3 tables this option does not appear.

Kind regards,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please spend some time reading over [ask] and edit your question to more clearly state what you wish to accomplish and what resources you have found to build your solution. I am assuming you are building comboboxes with the wizard. Have you researched how to build unbound comboboxes?

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables in a Query object. a query can be used in a ComboBox just like a table Object.